# Doctrine2 Query with cross tables

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, inner-join

does anybody know how to get doctrine2 to perform a query with tables joined that doesn't exist as entities like cross tables? I'd like to get a list of tags used for a certain entity ordered by the frequency of their use (for auto completion). I use the same tag table for tagging different entities each with a seperate cross table.

This mySQL query is working just fine:

```
SELECT t.* FROM Tag AS t INNER JOIN ItemXTag AS it ON it.tagId = t.id GROUP BY t.name ORDER BY COUNT(t.name) DESC
```

But i don't get doctrine to perform this query. I don't have an entity for ItemXTag and i don't need one (because it's just a cross table only containing relations and no data). 
I also have no relations to all other entities within the Tag entity. I only need the tags within the other entities, where i have defined a ManyToMany relation like this:

```
/**
 * Tags of item
 *
 * var Tag[]
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ItemXTag",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="itemId", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tagId", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *  )
 */
protected $tags = array();
```

If i create the query direclty like

```
$tags = $em->createQuery('SELECT t.* FROM \Application\Entity\Tag AS t INNER JOIN ItemXTag as it WHERE it.tagId = t.id GROUP BY t.name ORDER BY count(t.name) DESC')->getResult();
```

i get an error from doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:63 with the message "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 49 near 'ItemXTag': Error: Class 'ItemXTag' is not defined."

If i use the query builder like

```
$tags = $qb
    ->select('t')
    ->from('\Application\Entity\Tag', 't')
    ->innerJoin('ItemXTag', 'it', 'it.tagId = t.id')
    ->groupBy('t.name')
    ->orderBy('count(t.name)', 'DESC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

i get exactly the same error.

Can somebody help me with this query?

Sincerely
Gordon

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a slight error in query: 
Try this:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT t FROM \Application\Entity\Tag AS t INNER JOIN \Application\Entity\TagItemXTag as it WHERE it.tagId = t.id GROUP BY t.name ORDER BY count(t.name) DESC');
$tags = $query->getResult();
```

You must define an entity **TagItemXTag** here.

This might work.

Comment: As i already wrote, i don't have entity models for my cross reference tables and i don't need them. Entity Models are for representing data. Cross tables only contains relations and don't have any data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using a native query with a simple result set mapping to get back Tag entities.

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('\Application\Entity\Tag', 't');
$tags = $em->createNativeQuery('SELECT t.* FROM Tag AS t INNER JOIN ItemXTag as it ON it.tagId = t.id GROUP BY t.name ORDER BY count(t.name) DESC', $rsm)->getResult();
```

Works fine for me.